# How can I view images with unconventional filename extensions with VS Code's Image Preview feature?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am having trouble viewing files with .png encoding without the .png file extension in Visual Studio Code. It will only show the warning "The file is not displayed because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding.". Trying to select an editor only provides the options "text" or "hex".

So, is it possible to change the file association of a given file extension to inform VS Code to render that file as a .png, or other image type?

I have tried adding the lines `"files.associations": { "*.otherfiletype": "png" }` to my settings.json, but this has no effect.

Comment: ok, just so I understand this right. So you have a file like 'example.txt' with png encoding in it and you want vs code to read it as a png? Why don't you just convert this file by changing the filename-extension?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: Why don't you just convert this file by changing the filename-extension?

Comment: That is laborious given that it could just be viewed as a .png. Further, the file extension is required for other processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `workbench.editorAssociations` setting. Ex. in [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"workbench.editorAssociations": {
    "*.jpg2": "imagePreview.previewEditor",
},
```

It may still give a warning that

> The file is not displayed in the text editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding.

(at least- it did for me- your warningage may vary) But the change will allow you to click the "Open Anyway" button and be presented with the option to open it with the "Image Preview" (builtin) [custom editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/custom-editors).

Comment: Actually, this does not give me a warning, it works straight away! Thank you.